# How can I view git history/diff in Visual Studio Code before pulling

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have the git history extension which it lets me to compare local changes and the last pull commits.

How can I compare the latest commit on branch with my local files so that when my teammate pushes new commits, I don't run into as much conflicts when trying to git pull/commit my latest code?

Comment: **don't** work on the main branch, create a new branch and rebase that to the main branch **after** pull, merge feature branch to main branch and push

Comment: if you go left or right you always have to resolve the same amount of conflicts

Comment: clone the repo in a different directory and use a diff tool, git **only** diffs commits in the local repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, I use the Gitless extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maattdd.gitless (which I think is a fork of GitLens without the
blocked paid options)

I have a remote repository on which I've modified a readme to simulate the work of a colleague.

Then you go to the "Source Control" panel on the left, then Branches and in your working branch you have a "Compare main with origin/main" menu and this will show you the differences with your local working branch.

[image: VsCodeCapture]